# Time dependent variable (daily rainfall) in a cox survival analysis

Tags: survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I'm trying to analyse the effect of rainfall (a time dependent variable) on animal survival. In order for an animal to be measured as 'survived' in my study it needs to be found for a minimal period of ten days. As such, I want to look at the effect of total rainfall over this period on survival, keeping in mind that rainfall data was measured per day.

However, some animals died at different times (e.g. 2 days, 5 days, 8 days) before the 10 day cut off period, which means the number of days of rain measured for individuals is not always the same (e.g. total rain over five days before death for some individuals, compared to total rain over 7 days before death for others).

My question is: how should I encode the rainfall variable in a cox regression survival analysis if the rainfall variable is time dependent (changes every day), particularly if I'm interested in total rainfall over this period (the accumulated rainfall since day 0), and when survival length is different between individuals?

So far my code is as follows:

```
tstart = 0 for all individuals,
tdeath = length of time (days) after start when death occurred, 
endpoint = 0 for censored and 1 for death.   
res.cox  <-  coxph(Surv(tstart, tdeath, endpoint) ~ total.rain, data=data)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking for an explanation or code? Do you know how to split time dependent variables?

Comment: Hi user2974951, i think i have the code down but more so just wanted to know how to split the time dependent variable. If i was to split the variable into interval lengths of a day (e.g. rainfall on day 0 -1, 1-2, 2-3....) it would only then compare rainfall between individuals for each seperate interval rather than for the cumulative total rainfall from day 0 to day 'death'.  However, as the length of time to death varies between individuals, am I allowed to analyse the effect of TOTAL rainfall on survival WHEN the number of days used to calculate total rainfall varies between individuals?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here, maybe a plot of your data would help. Also, usually you would split time dependent variables in such a way, that you would create a split every time the time depenedent variable changes value for each individual separately, the last split would then include either death or censoring.

Comment: I think I might produce another question with example data included. Thanks user2974951